# Break lease after murder

Tags: residential-lease, florida, murder, breaking-the-lease

About 5 minutes after I came home tonight two neighbors were shot and murdered in front of their apartment. My unit is close enough that it's within the evidence zone.

My heart goes out to the families who must now deal with their loss.  However I don't want to stay here anymore. I live in the state of Florida and would like to know if I can break my lease without penalty.

Comment: While I'm sure this isn't easy for you, you're unlikely to have grounds to terminate the lease without breaching the agreement unless this type of scenario was specifically contemplated and addressed in it.

Comment: While you may not have a legal leg to stand on, you can always try to explain this to the landlord and try to figure something out. In the end we are all humans, and there is never harm in asking, especially if you will present something in return (for example you will move out now, but pay partial rent until he can re-rent it).

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  They refused any and all options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no, although [state legislative proposals](http://www.westword.com/news/trying-to-protect-stalking-and-sex-assault-victims-from-landlord-abuse-8751205) to allow this as a ground to break a lease have been considered in a number of places.

You would have to show that being in the evidence zone amounted to a "taking" under the 5th Amendment, of the apartment tenant's property which is almost never the case unless a very scientifically technical crime scene actually developed inside the apartment.